# A question about the derivative of functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I'm reading [Existence of solutions to a higher dimensional mean-field equation on manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5231), in this paper they defined
$$
E:=\left\{u \in H^m(M): \int_M u d \mu_g=0\right\},
$$
and
$$\|u\|:=\left(\int_M\left|\Delta_g^{\frac{m}{2}} u\right|^2 d \mu_g\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
They then found a $u_0$ such that
$$
I\left(u_0\right)<0 \quad \text { and } \quad\left\|u_0\right\| \geq 1 .
$$
then defined the inner product
$$\tag{1}
\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), v\right\rangle:=\left.\frac{d}{d t} I_\mu(u+t v)\right|_{t=0}
$$
and the norm
$$
\left\|I_\mu^{\prime}(u)\right\|:=\sup _{\|v\| \leq 1}\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), v\right\rangle .
$$

Consider the set of paths
$$
P:=\left\{\gamma \in C^0([0,1] ; E): \gamma(0)=0, \gamma(1)=u_0, \gamma(t) \in C^{\infty}(M) \text { for } 0 \leq t \leq 1\right\}.
$$
**In the last line of page10**, they choose $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $0 \leq \varphi \leq 1$ with $\varphi \equiv 1$ on $[-1, \infty)$ and $\varphi \equiv 0$ on $(-\infty,-2]$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $u \in E$ set
$$
\varphi_n(u):=\varphi\left(\frac{I_{\mu_n}(u)-c_\mu}{\mu_n-\mu}\right),
$$

then they defined a sequence $\gamma_n \in P$ and set
$$
\tilde{\gamma}_n(t):=\gamma_n(t)-\sqrt{\mu_n-\mu} \varphi_n\left(\gamma_n(t)\right) \frac{I_\mu^{\prime}\left(\gamma_n(t)\right)}{\left\|I_\mu^{\prime}\left(\gamma_n(t)\right)\right\|} \in E \cap C^{\infty}(M),
$$
**I'm confused about this step**, why $I_\mu^{\prime}\left(\gamma_n(t)\right)$ can be viewed as a function, isn't it an operator? In my understanding, it must be accompanied by a test function $v$ such as (1) to be meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition (1), you have
$$
I_\mu'(u) \in E^*$$
for all $u \in E$, i.e., the derivative $I_\mu'$ maps $E$ into $E'$.

Now, there are two possibilies for the final formula.

1. Since $E$ is a Hilbert space, you can identify $E^*$ with $E$. Thus, you have $R^{-1} I_\mu'(u)$ appearing in the final formula, where $R : E \to E^*$ is the Riesz isomorphism. In your case $R$ should be something like $\Delta_g^m$.
2. We use the embedding $E \hookrightarrow L^2(M) \hookrightarrow E^*$, i.e., every $v \in E$ can be viewed as a functional
   $$
   E \ni w \mapsto (w, v)_{L^2(M)}.$$
   Now, you could ask whether there exist $v \in E$ with
   $$
   (w,v)_{L^2(M)} = I_\mu'(u) w \qquad\forall w \in E.$$
   In this case, we can say $I_\mu'(u) \in E$.

I do not know which interpretation is used in the paper (I did not look into it), but the difference is crucial, since in "1.", you have an additional $\Delta_g^m$ sitting around.

Comment: The usage of norm is very confusing in this paper, in page10: (26), they use the inner product $\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}\left(v_n\right)-I_{\mu_n}^{\prime}\left(v_n\right), I_\mu^{\prime}\left(v_n\right)\right\rangle$, I can only treat it as the inner product induced by the norm, such as: $\left.(\alpha, \beta) \stackrel{\text { def }}{=} \frac{\|\alpha+\beta\|^2-\|\alpha-\beta\|^2}{4}\right)$.

Comment: Hi, would you mind checking if my idea is correct. My example is $$
I_\lambda(u)=\frac{1}{2} \int_M|\nabla u|^2 d \mu_g-\frac{\lambda}{2 m} \log \left(\int_M e^{2 m u} d \mu_g\right).
$$
If we treat $I_\mu^{\prime}(u)$ as a functional from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\eta \mapsto \int_M \nabla u \cdot \nabla \eta-\lambda \eta \frac{e^{2 m u}}{\int_M e^{2 m u} d \mu_g},
$$
which is linear, so we can apply Riesz representation theorem to get a $v \in E$ such that
$$
(v, \eta)_{L^2}=I_\mu^{\prime}(u)\eta,
$$
which we can use this $v$ to represent $I_\mu^{\prime}(u)$.

Comment: Then, recall that 
$$
\left\|I_\mu^{\prime}(u)\right\|:=\sup _{\|w\| \leq 1}\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), w\right\rangle,
$$
and
$$
\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), v\right\rangle:=\left.\frac{d}{d t} I_\mu(u+t v)\right|_{t=0},
$$
now if this $v$ represents $I_\mu^{\prime}(u)$, $\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), v\right\rangle$ should be the same as $(\sup _{\|w\| \leq 1}\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), w\right\rangle)^2.$

Comment: Then let's check:

$$
\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), v\right\rangle= \|v\|_2^{2}
$$
and
$$
\sup _{\|w\| \leq 1}\left\langle I_\mu^{\prime}(u), w\right\rangle=\sup _{\|w\| \leq 1}\left\langle v, w\right\rangle=\|v\|_2.
$$

which means that we can take some $v \in E$ to represent $I_\mu^{\prime}(u)$ in specific computation.

Comment: No, if you apply the Riesz representation theorem in $E$, you get $v \in E$ with $(v,\eta)_E = I'_\mu(u)\eta$ for all $\eta \in E$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why $L^2$ norm can't be a norm of $E$, I checked the definition but found no contradiction here. Perhaps I haven't thoroughly understood this theorem.

Comment: Of course, $L^2$ is a norm on $E$, but with this norm, $E$ is not complete.

Comment: Thanks! I get it.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that $E$ equipped with the norm defined in the second formula (look like another version of Sobolev norm) of the question is complete, so we can use Riesz. Is this correct?